# Data is reflected only when the Excel sheet is manually saved

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have an Excel report generation app using EPPlus. In one of sheets the formulas are getting dynamically updated, formulas referencing other sheets data. When I open the generated report I am able to see the formulas but the data is getting reflected only when I manually save the Excel sheet.

The reference sheet was also dynamically added, but when I changed it to static sheet the issue persisted.

Do I need to call some other function to update the formulas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok got it.

I need to call
     package.Workbook.Calculate()